# Cast undefined to 0

Tags: javascript, casting, integer, undefined

Is there a succinct operation in JavaScript (ES2015) that does this:

```
x => x === undefined ? 0 : x
```

I keep running into situations where I want to increment `x`, but it's initially undefined, so the code becomes:

```
foo.bar = (foo.bar === undefined ? 0 : foo.bar) + 1;
```

or

```
foo.bar = (foo.bar ? foo.bar : 0) + 1;
```

Is there a less repetitive way of doing this cast?

Comment: Did you try `(foo.bar || 0)`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
foo.bar = (foo.bar || 0) + 1;
```

should work.

Answer (score 5):

ES2020 and the nullish coalescing operator allows to simplify it:

```js
foo.bar = (foo.bar ?? 0) + 1;
```

Comment: Though this isn't necessarily any simpler than just a simple OR, as above

Comment: If foo.bar = NaN, the expression with an OR can provoke undesired results. The output of the nullish colaescing operator expression would be NaN as well. However, with a simple OR, you would get 1 as a result. @rubie

Comment: Yeah I guess that's desired or undesired based on context, but presumably if you're trying to cast foo.bar to a number, it's because you want to avoid NaN in most cases.

Comment: let _a = a(); let _b = b(); Imagine that a() and b() both return 0. 

Now you do: foo.bar = _a/_b.  You didn’t desired a NaN. You got it based on a division of two functions where you didn’t know the result beforehand.

Comment: Ah interesting, very good example. In the end, ?? and || aren't doing the same thing here, so there are going to be different use cases. The third answer is also interesting, but also has a big gap.

Answer (score 4):

Since `undefined + 1` is NaN, which is falsy, and `undefined` is falsy, you have a few options.

Assuming your numbers will never be negative (specifically, -1)

```
foo.bar = foo.bar + 1 || 1
```

Or this works for any values of `foo.bar`, though David's answer is probably a better idea.

```
foo.bar ? foo.bar++ : foo.bar = 1
```